# thread not being created again in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have some Python code that look this:

```
from ltpd import *
def thread_function():
    for i in range(5):
        if activatewindow('Confirm New Extension'):
            generatekeyevent('<left><space>')
            break
        time.sleep(1)

def main():
    for i in range some_big_range:
        thread = Thread(target = thread_function)
        thread.start()
        # Code that runs for really long time
```

I was expecting for a new thread to be created for every `i` in the loop. However, the thread is  being created only once. I need the thread to be started freshly for every iteration of the for loop. Can anyone tell me what's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Your `for` example has a syntax error so its hard to guess, but assuming it is something like `range(10)`, it will start 10 threads. So... how do you know more threads aren't starting? Each thread runs a maximum of 5 seconds (assuming "Do something") doesn't take very long.

Comment: Say that "Do something" is `print "bla"`. I know that the thread is not running because "bla" is not being printed.

Comment: Maybe because `some_condition` evaluates to `False`? Please don't post toy code, but use actual code instead and create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your example could easily be made into something we can test. Do that, and we can delve in.

Comment: Temporarily comment out that whole `if activatewindow...` clause and just `print "blah"`. You could also change it to `resp = activatewindow('Confirm New Extension')` + `print "response", resp` + `if resp:`. Also, wrap it all in a try/except that prints an error (`traceback.print_exc()`) is a good one to see if the thread is justdying.

Comment: @LukasGraf - I have made the edit to put the actual condition. I know that the condition evaluates to true because I can actually see the window being present. It evaluates `true` for other windows. May be the problem is with the "really long code" which I can't post because its over 500 lines long and I have tested that too. Apparently, I seem to have problem with a particular input only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every iteration a new thread is startet:

```
>>> from threading import Thread
>>> def fun(cnt):
...     print cnt
... 
>>> for i in range(5):
...     thread = Thread(target=fun, args=(i,))
...     thread.start()
... 
0
1
2
3
>>> 4
```